# Movie with an alien creature that eats people and reanimates their heads on tentacles

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I remember watching a movie in the 1980s where an alien creature came to Earth in the suburbs. It eats parents and neighbors and is able to stick their heads out on a tentacle or tongue and have them talk, but just their heads. The daughter tries to stop it and an alien bounty hunter shows up to stop it, but dies. I wish I could remember the name of this movie.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you're thinking of ***[TerrorVision](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092074/)*** (1986).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TerrorVision):

> *TerrorVision* is a 1986 American science fiction horror comedy film directed by Ted Nicolaou, produced and written by Albert and Charles Band and composed by Richard Band, all of whom would go on to found and work with Full Moon Features in 1989. *TerrorVision* was made by Empire International Pictures, the production company owned by Charles Band prior to Full Moon, and was released in February 1986.
>
> The story follows an alien creature sent to Earth, which ends up inside a household where three kids must take care of it to prevent it from going into a hungry rampage. While not a critical or commercial success, it later developed as a cult film, particularly a "so bad it's good" film.

[The whole film is up on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d5vqoziQZRA); you can view the creature reanimating a severed human head on the end of it's tongue at around the [32:36](https://youtu.be/HImF4wnL7jE?t=1956) mark and the alien bounty hunter shows up at around the [1:16:19](https://youtu.be/HImF4wnL7jE?t=4579) mark.

That video won't directly play on this site though, so here's the trailer instead.